# NSMutableArray + adding UIImageView - very simple but not working - arghh help

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

i'm dynamically creating imageviews (of a little burger icon, fyi) and want to keep track of them by using an mutable array. I'm declaring the array in my header as:

```
NSMutableArray *myBurgers;
```

And init my array in my viewDidLoad

```
NSMutableArray* myBurgers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
```

Here is my method for making the images and shoving into an array - currently my array count is returning 0 - and i've compiler error saying 'Unused variable 'myburgers'

```
-(void)burgerManGo:(CGPoint)location {

   burgerCount=burgerCount++;

    if(location.x<=(320) && location.y<=(480)){

    CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 65, 55); 
    UIImageView *myNewBurger = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect]; 
    [myNewBurger setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"burgerMan.png"]];
    myNewBurger.opaque = YES; // explicitly opaque for performance 
    [self.view addSubview:myNewBurger];

    //but adding to my array doesn't seem to work...
    [myBurgers addObject: myNewBurger];

    //because this always come back as 0
    NSLog(@"Array Size: %ld", [myBurgers count]);       

    } 

}
```

Any help, as ever, is much appreciated.

Mickey.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't create an array with capacity 0! It will instantly resize the first time you add something to it. You can just call `[NSMutableArray array]` to get an array of default initial capacity.

As for your actual problem: from what you've written, you're declaring a *new* variable inside viewdidLoad called myBurger. i.e. in viewDidLoad, you should have:

```
self.myBurgers = [NSMutableArray array];
```

and not:

```
NSMutableArray* myBurgers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
```

Note that the `self.myBurger =` will cause your new array to be retained (assuming you defined the myBurgers property to be retain, and not assign) -- which is what you want. Don't forget to `[myBurgers release]` in `dealloc`.

Comment: Yes it will. Assigning to a retained property increments the retain count.

Comment: Actually, arrayWithCapacity: is fine. arrayWithCapacity: does not set a maximum capacity, rather it creates an array with enough memory ready to accept a given number of items. Adding objects to an array made with arrayWithCapacity:0 should work just fine.  Granted, it is probably better to just use [NSMutableArray array]

Comment: Certainly, arrayWithCapacity:0 won't break anything, but is completely pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You have to retain the array you making in viewDidLoad:, now you have an autoreleased object, and will be gone after the runloop.

Do:

```
NSMutableArray* myBurgers = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0] retain];
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, all the asker needs to do is retain the array.

Comment: Um, no that's not the correct answer. All you've succeeded in doing is leaking the array; it's still not being assigned to the instance variable.

Comment: I'm was assuming that myBurgers was an instance variable type. I only put NSMutableArray in front of it for the typing/

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance in your `viewDidLoad` instead of assigning to the interface member.

Answer (score 0):

Bare in mind that

```
NSMutableArray* myBurgers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
```

is an auto released object

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

 myBurgers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:kMaxBurgersQty];



}

-(void)dealloc {
   [myBurgers release];
   myBurgers = nil;
}
```

That will grant that the burger array won't be autorelease somewhere in the middle of runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, your class declares an instance variable like so:

```
NSMutableArray *myBurgers;
```

You then override `viewDidLoad` as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // ...
    NSMutableArray *myBurgers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
    // ...
}
```

If that's the case, your `viewDidLoad` method is declaring a local variable, `myBurgers` that temporarily masks the instance variable with the same name. You then assign an autoreleased array to the local variable. The array is deallocated shortly after the return from `viewDidLoad`, but in any case it's never assigned to the instance variable.

To fix this, rewrite your `viewDidLoad` method as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // ...
    myBurgers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // ...
}
```

There's no point autoreleasing objects that you're assigning to instance variables; instead use `alloc` and the appropriate `init...` method. Also, as a previous poster noted, initializing a mutable array with a capacity of zero is fairly pointless. Either use a specific non-zero capacity (if you know in advance how many elements the array will contain), or else take the default.